# How to remove whitespace while drawing indicator with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I use plotly to create subplot indicator here.But the space in top and bottom too large. I set margin , but it not fix this case.
How can I remove white space?
Have any ideas?
Thanks
This is my source code here:

```
def show_indicator_rma(total, opened, closed,received, not_received ):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=5,specs=[[{"type": "indicator"},{"type": "indicator"},{"type": "indicator"},{"type": "indicator"},{"type": "indicator"} ]],horizontal_spacing = 0.1,vertical_spacing = 0.25)

    fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode = "number+delta",
        value = total,
        title = {"text": "Total units<br>"},
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},),
        row=1, col=1  )

    fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = opened,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Open"},
        gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, total],'visible': False},}
        ),
        row=1, col=2  
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = closed,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Closed"},
      gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, total],'visible': False},}
        ),
        row=1, col=3
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = received,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Received"},
        gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, total],'visible': False},}
        ),
        row=1, col=4
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = not_received,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Not Received"},
        gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, total],'visible': False},}    ),
        row=1, col=5
    )

    # fig.update_layout(title_text="Tickets")
    return fig
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50LMY.png)